# error downloading from OpenStreetMap ("..server replied: Gateway Time-Out")

Tags: openstreetmap, download

I've been trying to download OpenStreetMap data (vectorial > OpenStreetMap > Download data), but I get the error shown in the image below. Anyone know how to fix it? I have tried in different computers (laptops and pc), this error started to appearing today I used this plugin weeks ago.

I'm using QGIS 2.8.3, Windows 7, 64 bits.

[image: error downloading data from OpenStreetMap]

Sorry for the words in Spanish

Answer (score 2):

The Overpass API server you are using is currently down, see [platform status](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Platform_Status). There are other Overpass API instances available which you can try, assuming that QGIS allows to configure the server address.

Comment: Thank you ! I though that nobody want to help me, maybe as you say the server was down, but is on again now, do you think I need to change it anyway?

Comment: No, don't change it if it is working now. You are using the primary Overpass API server which is fine.

Answer (score 1):

It works now! it was not a failure in my pc, I guess it was an error from the OSM, and they fix it.

thanks anyway.

Yesterday I use this page https://mapzen.com/data/metro-extracts/ to get the layers, is good.